# office web addin URLs in manifest to local images

Tags: office-addins

I've created an office web addin using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio) instructions and I'm trying to publish it on AppSource.

All of the URLs in the manifest use `remoteAppUrl` e.g. "~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button16x16.png" so they'll work when the addin is running under different contexts.  The images are included in the addin so they should always be local to it - I don't want to host the images somewhere else.

When I debug the addin by running it in Visual Studio it works fine - remoteAppUrl gets replaced by a localhost URL and all the URLs work.

However if I use either `office-addin-manifest` or trying to upload it to AppSource I get manifest validation errors:

```
Error #1:
Invalid Manifest Resource Urls: The manifest Resource URLs are invalid.
  - Details: Urls should be secured, non-localhost and valid, Found invalid Urls : ~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html, ~remoteAppUrl/Home.html,

Error #2:
Malformed High Resolution Icon URL: The manifest high resolution icon URL must be well formed. Please see https://aka.ms/oackhighresolutionicon for details.
  - Details: ~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button64x64.png

Error #3:
Malformed Manifest Icon URL: The manifest icon URL must be well formed. Please see https://aka.ms/oackicon for details.
  - Details: ~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png
```

If I try validating the version of the manifest from debugging that has remoteAppUrl replaced with localhost, I get validation errors saying that localhost isn't a valid URL to use.

Which manifest am I supposed to be using to upload the addin to AppSource?